# How to change colors in Kendo Dropdownlist content?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I want to change color in Kendo `Dropdownlist` content text. I want to apply two colors in content text.

Ex lets take one item like

1. Bank balance 20$
2. other fund 200$`

Here i want to change red color only  for "20$" and "200$".

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

With [kendo.ui.DropDownList](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist) you can provide *template* which will be used for rendering items in list. E.g.

```
 <script>
     $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
         dataSource: dataSource,
         dataTextField: "Name",
         dataValueField: "Id",
         template: '<text>${data.Id} ${data.Name}' + 
                   '<span class='money'>${data.Amount}</span></text>'
     });
 </script>
```

Or if you are using server-side helpers:

```
Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("funds")
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("Id")
    .Template("text>${data.Id} ${data.Name}" + 
              "<span class='money'>${data.Amount}</span></text>")
```

Another sample of DropDownList customization [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/template.html).